# Facebook Connect OAuth Window Popup

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook

When I pop up the FB connect Oauth login window, how do I have it direct to a new page once the user has successfully signed in?

Right now, it's redirecting to the same page.

Comment: can u put some code? there are multiple ways to get the login button on a website, and hence exact solution will be different. just the code to generate the login button will do, or whatever else you think maybe useful in solving the question:)

Answer (score 0):

You use the redirect_uri GET parameter, passing it your URL.
[This pretty much covers it ALL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)